# Can I have a 100% height within a DIV that is itself 100% height?

Tags: css, css-float, height

I have a basic site structure which has:

1. A `Header` div which sits at the top of the screen
2. Two `Sidebar` divs for navigation which are floated left and right of the screen
3. A `Content` div which is in the middle of the sidebars (no float, it just has a margin left and right the same width as the sidebars so that it clears them)
4. A `Footer` div which sits at the bottom of the screen (its fixed in place using absolute positioning)

Can I fill the space between the `Header` and `Footer` at 100%? I want my `Sidebars` and `Content` to fill the remaining height space between the Header and Footer. Also I would like the Content area to have a vertical scrollbar if the content inside it is more than the height of the screen.

So far I have managed to only fix the `Header` and `Footer` at the top and bottom respectively. I have also floated the `Sidebar` to the left and right of the screens and the `Content` div in the middle. They all work but my Sidebars and Content divs are not the full height of the remaining screen space.

I started a JSFiddle here but its not working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/6YSuc

Comment: Must Header and Footer be fixed at top or bottom, even if you scroll?

Comment: @Oriol yes just like in a normal desktop application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `position: relative` to your elements so that they do not overlap each other. Also, assigning `height: 100%` to the parent element helps.

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSuc/1/).

Comment: thanks for this. but I want the footer to be fixed to the bottom of the screen and never move. and I need the `Content` and `Sidebar` divs to not go 'under' or 'over' that `Footer`

Comment: You only have to change the `position` to `fixed` for the footer to achieve that. Whether the footer comes over or under the sidebar and content can be adjusted according to its `z-index` attribute. Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSuc/4/).